# How to test code generator(written in python) which generates .c,.h files?

Tags: python, testing, code-generation

I am trying to test a code generator tool to verify if it's generating code(and files) as per some requirements. The tool is written in python. The inputs to the tool is a JSON File. The outputs of the tool are:

1. Lots of .c and .h files
2. a couple of.arxml(AUTOSAR XML Format) files.

A sample of requirements looks like:
->Based on a particular config in JSON file(input to the tool), it must a generate a particular macro(based on the configuration) and so on.

Currently I test this tool by manually opening the .c file(generated) and search inside it to verify if the macro got generated.

Can you anyone please provide some ways or ideas on automating this testing? Pointing to links/blogs are appreciated. Thanks in advance!!.

PS: I tried by creating a python exe which would test the scenario mentioned above. But I have >200 requirements for which I need to test each and realised that's a lot of tests to write. Any ways to simplify these would be very much helpful.

Comment: Look into the golden master technique, where you save the current generated code per json input and compare that against future runs, e.g., with `diff`. You could also use a C compiler to compile the generated code to detect syntax errors. I would not try to parse the generated code manually or use regular expressions to see if a macro or function is defined. Create a small test C program that calls the expected macro / function and see if that compiles.